# Exclude projects from solution build programmatically

Tags: c#, msbuild

I created an app to build projects from a solution using the `BuildManager` class.
I am trying to exclude test projects within my solution. Is there a way in C# code to exclude projects matching specific names? e.g. `*.test.proj`

Here is my code so far:

```
public bool Build()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Configuration", "Debug" },
        { "Platform", "Any CPU" },
        { "VisualStudioVersion", "14.0"}
    };

    string pathToLog = ConfigHelper.CheckConfig("ServiceBuildLogPath");

    ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
    BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc)
    {
        Loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger>() { new Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.FileLogger() { Parameters = "logfile=" + pathToLog + @"MSBuild.log" } },
        DefaultToolsVersion = "14.0"
    };

    BuildResult buildResult = null;

    BuildRequestData buildRequest;

    foreach (Solution solution in _services)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(solution.PathToSolution))
            {
                if (_nugetPackageRestore.Restore(solution.PathToSolution))
                {
                    buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(solution.PathToSolution, globalProperty, "4.0", new string[] { "Build" }, null);
                    buildResult = Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, buildRequest);

                    if (buildResult.OverallResult != BuildResultCode.Success)
                    {
                        if (buildResult.Exception != null)
                        {
                            throw buildResult.Exception;
                        }

                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to build solution {0}", solution.Name));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("Solution {0} is unavailable", solution.Name));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return buildResult != null && buildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to only include specific project / solution files in the build.

[Download only required solutions from workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051671/download-only-required-solutions-from-workspace/49065597#49065597)